# How do I send an XML message via HTTP POST to a test URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please note, I'm very beginner and still learning about javascript and back end concepts.

I have an HTML form that collects user information and on submit, it goes through validation and gets turned into an XML. I have it working to where it is an object in the console and outputs the code below but:

what I need to do is to send that XML via HTTP POST to a test URL and get a response back.

My test URL is https://plmdemo.infinityels.com/plm.net/lead/xml/Processor.ashx

I'm not sure where to go from here.

The URL expects XML like this:

```
<LeadRequest>
    <Username>test</Username>
    <Password>test</Password>
    <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
    <SSN>sdf</SSN>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Email>sdf@gmail.com</Email>
    <DOB>2018-07-22</DOB>
    <DriversLicense>sdf</DriversLicense>
    <DriversLicenseState>sdf</DriversLicenseState>
    <HomeAddress>sdf</HomeAddress>
    <HomeCity>sdf</HomeCity>
    <HomeState>AL</HomeState>
    <HomeZip>sdf</HomeZip>
    <TimeAtAddress>3</TimeAtAddress>
    <HomePhone>123-456-7890</HomePhone>
    <WorkPhone>123-456-7890</WorkPhone>
    <CellPhone>123-456-7890</CellPhone>
    <BankInfo>
        <BankName>Citi</BankName>
        <BankPhone>123-456-7890</BankPhone>
        <AbaNumber>1</AbaNumber>
        <CheckingAccount>2</CheckingAccount>
        <SavingsAccount>2</SavingsAccount>
        <AccountToUse>C</AccountToUse>
        <AccountLength>2</AccountLength>
    </BankInfo>
    <EmploymentInfo>
        <MonthlyIncome>12</MonthlyIncome>
        <PayFrequency>1</PayFrequency>
        <IncomeType>1</IncomeType>
        <PayrollType>1</PayrollType>
        <NextPayDay>2019-09-12</NextPayDay>
        <SecondNextPayDay>2019-09-26</SecondNextPayDay>
        <Employer>sdf</Employer>
        <Occupation>sdf</Occupation>
        <EmploymentLength>2</EmploymentLength>
        <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
    </EmploymentInfo>
    <LoanInfo>
        <Amount>300</Amount>
        <DueDate>2019-10-18</DueDate>
    </LoanInfo>
</LeadRequest>
```

Comment: With out knowing what your processor expects to receive. Any thing would be a guess.

Comment: Does it expect it to be PUT, POST or GET, as a file or input?

Comment: @JasonK honestly my knowledge on this is very minimal but the only thing my sheet says is "this URL accepts XML messages via HTTP POST and sends back response XML message. Request XML must contain one LeadRequest element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a some what useful error message back on this. I edited the SSN and that error went away.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><LeadRequest><Username>test</Username><Password>test</Password><FirstName>Bill</FirstName><LastName>Jones</LastName><SSN>sdf</SSN><Gender>F</Gender><Email>sdf@gmail.com</Email><DOB>2018-07-22</DOB><DriversLicense>sdf</DriversLicense><DriversLicenseState>sdf</DriversLicenseState><HomeAddress>sdf</HomeAddress><HomeCity>sdf</HomeCity><HomeState>AL</HomeState><HomeZip>sdf</HomeZip><TimeAtAddress>3</TimeAtAddress><HomePhone>123-456-7890</HomePhone><WorkPhone>123-456-7890</WorkPhone><CellPhone>123-456-7890</CellPhone><BankInfo><BankName>Citi</BankName><BankPhone>123-456-7890</BankPhone><AbaNumber>1</AbaNumber><CheckingAccount>2</CheckingAccount><SavingsAccount>2</SavingsAccount><AccountToUse>C</AccountToUse><AccountLength>2</AccountLength></BankInfo><EmploymentInfo><MonthlyIncome>12</MonthlyIncome><PayFrequency>1</PayFrequency><IncomeType>1</IncomeType><PayrollType>1</PayrollType><NextPayDay>2019-09-12</NextPayDay><SecondNextPayDay>2019-09-26</SecondNextPayDay><Employer>sdf</Employer><Occupation>sdf</Occupation><EmploymentLength>2</EmploymentLength><Phone>123-456-7890</Phone></EmploymentInfo><LoanInfo><Amount>300</Amount><DueDate>2019-10-18</DueDate></LoanInfo></LeadRequest>';

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $xml
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://plmdemo.infinityels.com/plm.net/lead/xml/Processor.ashx', false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: So I would create a PHP file and have method="post" action="index.php" on my form tag? I have not worked with PHP. Do I see the response in the console?

Comment: If you want to have one page form you don't need to put in the action tag it will auto call itself.  Currently the result will be displayed in the browser. If you create with just the code I submitted. We are kinda getting scope creep on the question. To get good answers on this site it helps to have precise questions.

Comment: I apologize, and appreciate your help! This is my first question on this site and I don't really know what I should be asking since this subject is very new to me. I'll try and figure it out with what you provided me with.

Comment: No worries. It's easy to get convoluted. If you have problems processing a form just ask a new question. Make it simple and some one will be able to help you out. You know what the console it your already miles ahead.

Comment: Also if the answer your question. C kick on the check mark. Then the question will be marked ans answered.

Comment: Appreciate the patience and kind words. Marked as answered!